# Trouble when using firebase_messaging package, in "making Application class" step

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am following the intruction to use firebase_messaging package (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging). In the step of making Application class, I see this error (see picture). When I hover on *'FlutterApplication'*, the IDE show *'Cannot resolve symbol 'FlutterApplication'* [image]

Comment: Ignore this erros

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to **"Invalidate Caches / Restart..."** every time it happens:

[image]